# Python extract substring but preserve whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, string

In python, I would like to extract a substring from a line but preserve the whitespaces that occur in the substring. For example, in the following:

```
34  -1  1   10  C2H4      + OH      = C2H3     + H2O                8.020E+13  0.00   5955.0
35  -0.301029996    0.301029996 2   C2H3      + O2      = CH2O     + HCO                4.000E+12  0.00   -250.0
36  -0.477121255    0.477121255 3   C2H3      + HCO     = C2H4     + CO                 6.034E+13  0.00      0.0
37  -1  1   10  C3H5       =  C2H2+CH3      2.397E+48 -9.90  8.208E+04
38  -1  1   10  C2H4(+M)   =  C2H2+H2(+M)   1.800E+13  0.00  7.600E+04
39  -1  1   10  C2H3+O2    = C2H2+HO2       2.120E-06  6.00  9.484E+03
40  -0.505149978    0.505149978 3.2 C2H3+H     =  C2H2+H2       2.000E+13  0.00  2.500E+03
41  -0.505149978    0.505149978 3.2 C2H2+H(+M) = C2H3(+M)       3.110E+11  0.58  2.589E+03
42  -1  1   10  C2H2+O2    =  HCCO+OH       2.000E+08  1.50  3.010E+04
43  -0.698970004    0.698970004 5   C2H2+O     =  HCCO+H        1.430E+07  2.00  1.900E+03
44  -1  1   10  C2H2+OH    =  CH2CO+H       2.190E-04  4.50 -1.000E+03
45  -0.477121255    0.477121255 3   CH2CO+H    =  CH3+CO        1.100E+13  0.00  3.400E+03
```

I would like to extract the substring starting from the fifth element until the third from the end of the line yielding the chemical reaction with whitespaces intact like so:

```
C2H4      + OH      = C2H3     + H2O
```

I tried with `split` like so but I lose whitespaces:

```
chemical_reaction=' '.join(aline.split()[4:-3])
```

I get:

```
C2H4 + OH = C2H3 + H2O
```

Comment: Do you have more lines with different data ?

Comment: @noob edited question with more data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\s*(?:\S+\s+){4}(.+?)(?:\s+\S+){3}\s*$
```

and grab captured group #1 which is being returned by middle path `(.+?)`. On either side of this group we are matching 4 non-space words and 3 non-space words.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN9xB2/6)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be working for most cases but crashes before parsing the whole data. The data has tabs and spaces mixed. Could it be that the regex is not able to handle such a combination? Ok, now I know why it failed for a particular case: it had a trailing whitespace at the end of line. Fixed.

Comment: Yes indeed `\s*$` will take care of trailing white-spaces.